# Addressing to variables declared with 'self' without accessing any instance of the class

Tags: python, oop, self

In this example, can I look for keys of `x` without touching any instance of `C`?

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = dict(one=1, two=2)
```

My purposes:

I have a `ElementClass` and `ManagerClass`. `ElementClass` contains a structure iplemented with dict. And `ManagerClass` methods must validate input by comparing keys of input dict with keys of prototype dict keys.

How can this be implemented without obscurity?

**UPD:**
People say that if I declare `x` with `self`, it means, I already touched instance.
Actually not always:

```
class C:
    x = dict(one=1, two=2)

    def m(self):
        print(id(self.x)

x = C()
```

In this example I not declare `x` with `self`, but I can address to it with `self`.

Comment: What do you mean? `self` *is* an instance of `C`, so you’ve already touched it, and it’s not anywhere else besides.

Comment: @minitech see UPD section please

Comment: @GillBates: Your update uses a class variable, which is bound to the class, not to a specific instance. Changing it will change it for *all* instances of that class.

Comment: It's still horribly vague. What is your intent? [Smells like an XY problem for now.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Blender I know, I just want to show, that `self` is not uberstrictly  explicit as @minitech says

Comment: @property? @classmethod? Perhaps... Learn more at : http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Comment: @GillBates: `self` refers to the current instance of your class. You can't use `self` without a class instance.

Comment: Please post a short, working example of the relevant methods in `ElementClass` and `ManagerClass`. As it is, you keep talking **around** the issue, instead of head on. We could probably get straight to business with an example to work with.

Comment: -1 for arguing that correct answers are wrong. Also voting to close, as if you simply don't accept how python works, there is no answer to your question.

Comment: @Marcin Probably I really asked stupid question

Answer (score 3):

Not with your current setup. You can, however, make `x` a class variable:

```
class C(object):
    x = dict(one=1, two=2)
```

You can make use of class variables and keep a class-wide list of instances:

```
class C(object):
    instances = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = dict(one=1, two=2)

        self.instances.append(self)
```

Now, you can iterate over all instances of `C` by accessing the class variable:

```
for instance in C.instances:
    print instance.x
```

---

Using class variables for this isn't a good idea. Just add a list to your manager class:

```
class Manager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = []

    def is_valid(self, element):
        return 42 not in element.x

    def validate(self):
        for element in self.elements:
            if not self.is_valid(element):
                return False

        return True

class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, manager):
        manager.elements.append(self)

        self.x = {'one': 1, 'two': 2}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    element1 = Element(manager)
    element2 = Element(manager)
    element3 = Element(manager)

    print manager.validate()
```

Comment: What if I want to declare some kind of prototype of structure for instances, using dict, and in upper in class in hierarchy validate input by comparing keys in it with keys in this prototype dict?

Comment: @GillBates: Can you explain your *exact* situation?

Comment: Using the class name instead of `self` makes the code clearer.

Comment: @sr2222: You'll run into problems if you rename the class. Usually I just make class variables uppercase.

Comment: @Blender I have a huge DB. Instances of ElementClass stores data which aggregated to them from db in specific way. ManagerClass method should know how to check if some data in input contains in some of instances of ElementClass. But also it must check for input validity.

Comment: @GillBates: So how does my example code not solve your problem?

Comment: @Blender `ManagerClass` is class operates not in single instance of `ElementClass` but with all instances of `ElementClass`. Actually describing it fully will be too heavy. I solved my problem by implementing some kind of `frozendict` class

Comment: @GillBates: Why is that a requirement?

Comment: @Blender I didn't say rename the class, I meant use the class name instead of `self` when referencing class variables from within member methods.  Just makes it more explicit and easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

An instance attribute does not exist without an instance for it to be an attribute of.  You can access a class attribute from an instance of that class, but in that case, the attribute belongs to the class itself, not an instance.  You could look in to a simple decorator or the descriptor protocol to create a structure that catalogs all `x` values for every instance through a central interface and allows the class to access the data differently than the instances...